# What area of Mathematics tells what functions are integrable in terms of elementary functions?

Tags: integration

Everybody knows that the integrals Gaussian, $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ and another bunch of functions can not be expressed in terms of elementary functions. I saw that Differential Galois Theory deals with this but it is mostly used in Differential Equations. I would like to know if there are other branches of math working in this kind of problems.

Comment: Integration is the solution to a special kind of differential equation, so maybe this is still the right thing to look for?

Comment: [Differential algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra) is the area for studying such things in general, which encompasses differential Galois theory. The particular examples you mention don't need the full force of differential Galois theory though, [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) is enough.

Comment: It really has to be an algebra problem though, in some sense, since the question is if something is expressible in a certain form, not whether the something exists in some way. Compare with how analysis easily tells us how many roots a polynomial has, but to factor that polynomial in a certain form is much harder (and often impossible, as Galois theory tells us).